# How to add background drawable to Action Bar Tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

Hello I am working on an android application where I require to set the drawable to the action bar `Tabs` as like the screenshot. I did not find any method on `Tab` to set the drawable. Please help me to achieve this.

[image]

```
public class PayStubActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_stub);

        // adding action bar tabs to the activity
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        Tab firstTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_current_tab)).setTabListener(this);
        Tab secondTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_all_tab)).setTabListener(this);

        // add the tabs to the action bar
        mActionBar.addTab(firstTab);
        mActionBar.addTab(secondTab);

        // set the navigation mode the Action Bar Tabs
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // user is selected first tab
        if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CurrentPayStubFragment());
        } else {
            // user is selected second tab.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

}
```

Thanks in advance.